# Microsoft VSTS Set Default Work Item State After Pull Request Completes

Tags: azure-devops

I currently use Microsoft VSTS as my teams primary project management system and I have run into an issue.  Currently we have user stories that we create pull requests against, once a pull request is completed the linked work item(s) get set to a "closed" stated instead of a "resolved" state.  We do not currently have our test engineers tests out features/user stories in a separate environment that is defined by the pull request'ed code, we do all our acceptance testing in our development branch.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Not sure I understand what your question is. Could you clarify?

Comment: Basically a developer creates a branch, works within the branch, once the work in the branch is completed the developer creates a pull request and attaches work item to the pull request e.g. a User Story, once the pull request is completed the User Story is automatically set to Closed instead of Resolved.

Answer (score 5):

> we have user stories that we create pull requests against, once a pull
>   request is completed the linked work item(s) get set to a "closed"
>   stated instead of a "resolved" state.

The reason for the linked user stories state changed to closed once the PR completed it caused the **Complete linked work items after merging** option is selected. So once the PR is completed, the related linked work items state are changed to complete.

[image]

And you can find in [state categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/workflow-and-state-categories#state-categories), that shows user story completed category for user story state is closed. So that’s why the state changed to closed instead of resolved.

[image]

If you want the linked work items state keep the same even the PR is completed, you just need to **deselect the Complete linked work items after merging option** when completing a PR.

[image]

Comment: @PiotrZaremba Did the answer help you solve the problem?

Comment: Is it possible to change this from Closed to some other state that's still In-Progress?

Comment: No, it's designed for the PR is completed, that means the lined work items also completed. If the linked work items shoudn't closed even when PR is completed, you can deselect the Complete linked work items after merging option and change the state manually.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the follow-up question, but it's too big for a comment.  But I'm just trying to clarify @Marina-MSFT's answer.

@Marina-MSFT: I work with Piotr, and I'd like to be able to control the status changes per issue when we click "automatically *update* related work items".  I thought onsite TFS had this, and I know JIRA + Bamboo + BitBucket has it (for GitHub see below).

If the VSTS team is not interested we might write it ourselves with an extension, but we definitely see this as useful for others, so of course we wanted to ask first.

---

#### Research & Links

I found the original uservoice for this VSTS feature:
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/18788428-auto-close-work-item-after-pull-request-complete

It links to GitHub commit comments `fix/fixes/resolve/resolves` etc:
https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords/

> The following keywords, followed by an issue number, will close the issue:
>
> close
>   ...
>   fixes
>   fixed
>   resolve
>   resolves

But while the commit comments are flexible the status change is **not** -- GitHub will **only close** the issue.

---

#### Our *Flow*

`|            Branch | feature/123    | master | N/A       | N/A    |
|       Environment | local (branch) | DEV    | TEST      | PROD   |
|-------------------|----------------|--------|-----------|--------|
| User Story status | Active         | Active | Resolved  | Closed |
|        Bug status | Active         | Active | Resolved  | Closed |
|       Task status | Active         | Closed | Closed    | Closed |`

Comment: Thanks for your detail feedback @yzorg. And we also aim to build the VSTS/TFS as the products that users love. And there has an user voice about this feature https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6380299-update-work-items-on-commit-for-git, you can vote and follow up.